# NodeJS and PDFKit: how to make first page to be landscape?

Tags: node.js, node-pdfkit

So, I've got a document:

`var doc = new PDFDocument;`

The docs tells me that *The first page of a PDFKit document is added for you automatically*, so there's no need to add it manualy. But how can I meke it to be landscape?

This one

```
doc.addPage({
    size: 'LEGAL',
    layout: 'landscape'
});
```

works, but adds another page.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

So it was quite obvious:

```
var doc = new PDFDocument(
        {
            layout : 'landscape'
        }
    );
```

Comment: this answer is not working

Answer (score 1):

You can disable autoFirstPage

```
const doc = new PDFDocument({ autoFirstPage: false });
doc.addPage({
    size: 'LEGAL',
    layout: 'landscape'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using NodeJs you can just configure the PDF Document (without add pages)

```
//import the module
const PDFDocument = require("pdfkit-table");
//start pdf document
let doc = new PDFDocument({ 
                margin: 30, 
                size: 'A3', 
                layout: 'landscape' 
});
```